# jQuery animated scroll to top anchor not working?

Tags: jquery, animation, anchor

I've got a block of jQuery code that is supposed to scroll (animated) a user to the top of a page when a link is clicked in the footer. Now, it works on my computer (in development) but on a production server, it doesn't animate, it just jumps to the top. Any ideas?

```
        /* scroll to top */
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
                return false;
            });
        });
```

the link is in the footer

```
<a href="#top">back to top</a>
```

the anchor is at the top, right after the opening of the body tag

```
<a name="#top"></a>
```

EDIT/UPDATE:
it appears ALL jQuery is not working on the website.. I've linked to the jQuery library using Google's API

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why would this work from my computer, but not from a cloud server?

Comment: Silly question: have you uploaded the jquery library and linked it properly in code? Only reason I ask is that it works locally and not on prod.

Comment: it's linked to the jQuery library using Google's API (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js)

Comment: where is this hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `id` instead of `name`:

```
<a id="top"></a>
```